# How to use if statements to return DataFrame items to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My apologies if this is extremely basic. I've been trying to teach myself to code through quarantine, so I'm quite new. My goal is to create an if statement that returns each ticker and its corresponding position into certain columns in Excel based on the group the ticker belongs to.

The tickers and positions are contained in a DataFrame I've converted to two lists, I also have converted it to a dictionary. Nothing seems to work to solve the whole problem. My dictionary uses Tickers as keys and Positions as values. My lists contain all Tickers and all Positions. Pasting what is returned from print(dict) below:

```
{'Position': {'AKERBP': 0, 'APA': -189, 'AR': 0, 'ASCRES': 100, 'CENREP': 0, 'CHK': 0, 'CITHOL': 230, 'CLR': 900, 'CNX': 702, 'CPE': 230, 'CRK': -8, 'CRROCK': -497, 'CVECN': 139, 'DOUBEA': 265, 'ENDENR': 504, 'EQT': 482, 'FANG': 0, 'GPOR': 0, 'GRTWST': 0, 'HILCRP': -843, 'INDNAT': 120, 'JAG': 0, 'LPI': 304, 'MEGCN': 500, 'MSSCRK': 0, 'MTDR': 237, 'MUR': 0, 'NOG': 0, 'OAS': 0, 'OVV': 530, 'OXY': 879, 'PARSLY': 421, 'PDCE': -89, 'QEP': 0, 'RRC': -436, 'SM': -198, 'SRCI': 0, 'SWN': 532, 'SXCP': 862, 'TPGE': 0, 'VIICN': 89, 'VNOM': 0, 'VRI': 987, 'WES': 89, 'WLL': 0, 'WPX': 654, 'XOG': 0}}
```

The two lists I've created are named tickers and positions. The tickers list contains all of the dictionary keys (AKERBP, APA, AR..) the positions list contains all of the values (0, -189, 0...).

Below are my groupings for my if statements:

```
permian = ['APA', 'CENREP', 'CRROCK', 'DOUBEA', 'ENDENR', 'JAG', 'LPI', 'MSSCRK', 'MTDR', 'OVV', 'OXY', 'PARSLY', 'VNOM', 'WES', 'WPX']
beta = ['CLR', 'CPE', 'CVECN', 'HILCRP', 'MEGCN', 'NOG', 'OAS', 'QEP', 'SM', 'WLL', 'VIICN']
gas = ['AR', 'ASCRES', 'CNX', 'CRK', 'EQT', 'FANG', 'GPOR', 'RRC', 'SWN', 'VRI']
```

I've done the following thus far:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Ticker(s)')['Position'].sum())
tickerlist = df.groupby('Ticker(s)')['Position'].sum().to_frame('Position').reset_index()
tickers = tickerlist['Ticker(s)'].values.tolist()
p=3  
b=3
g=3
o=3

for ticker in tickers:
    tickers = "%s %s"%(tickers,ticker.strip())
    if ticker in permian:
        sheet.cell(row=p, column=9).value = ticker
        p += 1
    elif ticker in beta:
        sheet.cell(row=b, column=12).value = ticker
        b += 1
    elif ticker in gas:
        sheet.cell(row=g, column=15).value = ticker
        g += 1
    else:
        sheet.cell(row=o, column=18).value = ticker
        o += 1
```

This method uses one of my lists, and it puts the tickers in the proper columns, I'm just having a hard time getting the positions to follow. I tried to use my dictionary instead, hoping I could use my for loop to populate the cells with both Tickers and Positions using the following:

```
dict=df.to_dict()
for key, value in dict.items():
    if key in permian:
        sheet.cell(row=p, column=9).value = str(key)
        sheet.cell(row=p, column=10).value = str(value)
        p += 1
    elif key in beta:
        sheet.cell(row=b, column=12).value = str(key)
        sheet.cell(row=b, column=13).value = str(value)
        b += 1
    elif key in gas:
        sheet.cell(row=g, column=15).value = str(key)
        sheet.cell(row=g, column=16).value = str(value)
        g += 1
    else:
        sheet.cell(row=o, column=18).value = str(key)
        sheet.cell(row=o, column=19).value = str(value)
        o += 1
```

This didn't work for me. My entire dictionary ended up in cell R3. If I can modify my code to get it all in one for loop, that would be preferable. However, given I know that my first code works, I could also search for the dictionary's key in Excel (since that populates correctly) and write a code that would populate its value next to it. I just haven't been able to figure out how to get that far. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll get a lot more help if you post some of your data that can be easily copied and pasted. Try posting the output of `df.head(20).to_dict()`

Comment: I edited my post and added the output of my dictionary. I hope that is more clear. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Position': {'AKERBP': 0, 'APA': -189, 'AR': 0, 'ASCRES': 100, 'CENREP': 0, 'CHK': 0, 'CITHOL': 230, 'CLR': 900, 'CNX': 702, 'CPE': 230, 'CRK': -8, 'CRROCK': -497, 'CVECN': 139, 'DOUBEA': 265, 'ENDENR': 504, 'EQT': 482, 'FANG': 0, 'GPOR': 0, 'GRTWST': 0, 'HILCRP': -843, 'INDNAT': 120, 'JAG': 0, 'LPI': 304, 'MEGCN': 500, 'MSSCRK': 0, 'MTDR': 237, 'MUR': 0, 'NOG': 0, 'OAS': 0, 'OVV': 530, 'OXY': 879, 'PARSLY': 421, 'PDCE': -89, 'QEP': 0, 'RRC': -436, 'SM': -198, 'SRCI': 0, 'SWN': 532, 'SXCP': 862, 'TPGE': 0, 'VIICN': 89, 'VNOM': 0, 'VRI': 987, 'WES': 89, 'WLL': 0, 'WPX': 654, 'XOG': 0}})
```

When you run `df.to_dict()` the keys are the column names, which is why I expect that it's always writing to your default column:

```
print(df.to_dict())
```

#### Output

```
'Position': {'AKERBP': 0,
  'APA': -189,
  'AR': 0,
  'ASCRES': 100,
  'CENREP': 0,
  'CHK': 0,
  ...
```

If you want the keys to be the names of the tickers, you can run `.to_dict()` on just the `Position` series:

```
print(df['Position'].to_dict())
```

#### Output

```
{'AKERBP': 0,
 'APA': -189,
 'AR': 0,
 'ASCRES': 100,
 'CENREP': 0,
 'CHK': 0,
 'CITHOL': 230,
...
```

Thus your code would look something like

```
d=df["Position"].to_dict()
for key, value in d.items():
    if key in permian:
        sheet.cell(row=p, column=9).value = str(key)
        sheet.cell(row=p, column=10).value = str(value)
        p += 1
    elif key in beta:
        sheet.cell(row=b, column=12).value = str(key)
        sheet.cell(row=b, column=13).value = str(value)
        b += 1
    elif key in gas:
        sheet.cell(row=g, column=15).value = str(key)
        sheet.cell(row=g, column=16).value = str(value)
        g += 1
    else:
        sheet.cell(row=o, column=18).value = str(key)
        sheet.cell(row=o, column=19).value = str(value)
        o += 1
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df.to_clipboard()` at a point in your code when you have the dataframe in a format that you want it in to copy into Excel.

`df.to_clipboard()` copies your dataframe into the system clipboard, allowing you to paste it nicely into Excel.

Just noting as well that it's hard to know your exact objective. It seems like you only want to use Excel as a backup but it is the key question you ask in the title.

Comment: Thank you for this tip! I have changed the title of my question and added a few clarifying sentences to make my goal more clear.